# Foldmethod=marker and syntax at the same time?

Tags: vim

Is it possible for a same file to use folding based on both markers and syntax ?

Answer (score 6):

Since `foldmethod` can only be set to one at a time, I think the only way you could really do this would be to use `:set foldmethod=expr` and hack about with `foldexpr`, and even then I'm not sure it would be able to do exactly what you want.

So, short answer: no

Long answer: maybe, muck about with `foldexpr` if you dare to see if you can get the desired results

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can emulate your markers by additional syntax rules?

But hard to tell without more input.

Answer (score 1):

The AutoFold.vim plugin attempts to address this: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=925

As an alternative, I thought I'd have a little go myself, by introducing a new syntax rule for markers.  Unfortunately this needs to be declared before any syntax rules for comments, or the comment rule will mask our marker rule.

So here is what I tried to insert my rule early:

```
:syn clear

:syn region myMarkerFold matchgroup=myDummyGroup start="{{{" end ="}}}" transparent fold

:exec "runtime! syntax/" . &filetype . ".vim"
```

It didn't quite work.  The last line immediately cleared my custom rule.  Drop the last line, and folding works, but of course none of the language will be syntax-matched or highlighted!  (By the way, I was testing this on a .vim file.)