# Code folding regions in ruby on VIM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I know not everyone like code folding, but as a convert to Rails and a convert to VIM, I want one of the conveniences back that I had in Visual Studio.Net.  I want to be able to place arbitrary #region #endregion tags and have VIM fold them for me like everything else.

I have syntax code folding turned on and normal def..end folding works fine, I just want to augment that with #regions.

I did some googling and thought that I could do this in a ruby.vim in my syntaxes folder, but it didn't work, and I don't know enough to debug whether it was bad code that I copied over or if it just "doesn't work that way."

```
let b:match_words = '\s*#\s*region.*$:\s*#\s*endregion'
```

This is my only line in syntax/ruby.vim.  In fact, the file wasn't there before I started, even though ruby highlighting is working fine. (which also throws big red flags for me - I haven't a clue where the ruby/rails syntax, unless its in the rails.vim plugin, but I can't find it there either.

Can someone lend me a thread so that I can follow it and figure this out?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I found some other code snippets and tried this version instead, which *almost* gets me there:

```
syn region vimFoldRegion
  \ start="#region"
  \ end="#endregion"
  \ skip=+"\%(\\"\|[^"]\)\{-}\%("\|$\)\|'[^']\{-}'+
  \ transparent fold
  \ keepend extend
  \ containedin=ALLBUT,@vimNoFold
```

This lets me fold the region, but all of the code inside the region is shown like its a comment.  I've tried different variations of the parameters on the syn, but I'm not grokking it.

Answer (score 3):

Vim can fold regions based on markers if you set `foldmethod=marker`.  The default markers are `{{{` and `}}}`, though I'm pretty sure you could override these to be `#region` and `#endregion`.  The problem is you then lose the ability to fold based on syntax.  There's another Stack Overflow question dealing with combining the two fold methods [1], but the conclusion there is that it's not possible to do both simultaneously.

For what it's worth, I find that vim's syntax-based code-folding is horrendously slow for large Ruby files, so you might find yourself wanted to switch to a marker-only fold method if you run into the same problem.

[1] [Foldmethod=marker and syntax at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757194/foldmethod-marker-and-syntax-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Actually, unless I'm missing something the {{{ }}} does exactly what I needed.  Even with foldmethod=syntax.  If I put {{{ #Validations for example then everything in the block gets folded with a message on the fold of "Validations", which is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  Will see if there are any unforeseen consequences of that...

Comment: Ah, never mind I spoke too soon, my test was bad and rails is rejecting my file with those markers in there.  But they WERE folding properly. Dang.

Comment: You can put the markers in a comment, like this: `# {{{ Validations`. That way, Ruby won't try to interpret the curly braces.

Comment: That doesn't work.  The markers won't fold if the "#" is in front of them.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're doing it without setting `foldmethod=marker`. In that case, it's interpreting `{{{` and `}}}` as part of Ruby's syntax and folding based on that. (Also the Ruby interpreter sees those and will try to parse them as Ruby code.)  With `foldmethod=marker`, what I said about putting the marker in a comment is valid, but then you lose the syntax-based folding.